# How I need to solve error ini one signal react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

This is my code, I am using hooks and also already try with class component too, but I faced some error

```
useEffect(() => {
OneSignal.setLogLevel(6, 0);
OneSignal.init('a6a1f13d-8823-4d98-86c9-d99aef433795', {
  kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false,
  kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: false,
  kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption: 2,
});
OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(2);

OneSignal.addEventListener('received', onReceived);
OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', onOpened);
OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', onIds);

return () => {
  OneSignal.removeEventListener('received', onReceived);
  OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', onOpened);
  OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', onIds);
}}, []);



const onReceived = (notification) => {
console.log('Notification received: ', notification);}

const onOpened = (openResult) => {
console.log('Message: ', openResult.notification.payload.body);
console.log('Data: ', openResult.notification.payload.additionalData);
console.log('isActive: ', openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
console.log('openResult: ', openResult)}



const onIds = (device) => {
console.log('Device info: ', device)}
```

TypeError: _reactNativeOnesignal.default.init is not a function. (In '_reactNativeOnesignal.default.init('a6a1f13d-8823-4d98-86c9-d99aef433795')', '_reactNativeOnesignal.default.init' is undefined)

Comment: Please don't use images for the code, and simply add the code as part of the question.

Comment: yeah i did bro , can you help me ?

Comment: Could you try using `react-native-onesignal:3.1.4` instead of the version you have right now, and check if the problem is solved?

Comment: Yeah i see , i already done with that (new version) . They havent released their offical usage documentation. Thank you bro

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I already solved this issues, its turn out One Signal changed their method with the new vesion. So the function already different now. Thanks all.

Edit : https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal/issues/1138

Comment: It would be more helpful for others experiencing the same issue if you shared a link to your solution. For instance, even the [official OneSignal documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup), see step #5, would be helpful, thanks.